# What does a kubernetes namespace represents in cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

What is the physical representation of a namespace in cluster (I am using AWS) is it an EC2 server?

Can someone help me understand by giving a metaphor of what is the physical representation of:

1. Cluster
2. Namespace
3. Pods
4. Containers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is - there is no physical representation of a namespace.

A `namespace` is a high-level abstraction that logically groups and manages Kubernetes resources (for example by type of environment development/staging/production). This helps in separating resources in the way that a resource from one namespace does not have access to the resources in other namespaces.

A `cluster` is a group of machines.

A `container` represents a real docker container running in one of the cluster nodes. You could assume a virtual image running inside a physical machine.

A `pod` represents group of containers (usualy 1 container, but can be more in case of sidecar deployment) deployed from single deployment resource (`Deployment`, `ReplicaSet` etc).

Answer (score 8):

Let's think of `namespace` as linux file system and ignore the fact of mounted directories for the sake of this question:

```
/srv => namespace-1
/var => namespace-2
/mnt => namespace-3
/bin => namespace-4
```

- All these 4 directories belongs to same `/`
- Inside a directory, you can have different type of files
- If you do `ls /srv` you won't see files in `/var`
- Different users can have different type of permissions on each directory

Now let's apply above 4 points in from the view of k8s namespace

- All these 4 `namespaces` belongs to same kubernetes cluster
- Inside a `namespace`, you can have different type of kubernetes objects
- If you do `kubectl get deployments` from `namespace-1`,  you won't see deployments in `namespace-2`
- Different `users` can have different type of authorization on each `namespaces`